# wpf combobox dropdown shows at top left corner of the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox with a custom style, but the dropdown items are rendered in the top left of the screens, at 0,0.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomNetworkComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="175"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource NetworkComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                                     Foreground="{StaticResource Black13}" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                     Focusable="True" Background="{x:Null}" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>
                        <Popup Name="PART_Popup"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton}">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource Black88}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Black67}"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="PART_Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I have tried several different "solutions" suggested by a Google search for the issue, but it hasn't worked so far.

the combobox is inside a grid which is an Item from a List view which is filled with data through the VM.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Task" Margin="0,0,30,0" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=IsCurrentComputer, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxIndexer}}" Style="{StaticResource CustomNetworkComboBox}"
                                TextBlock.FontFamily="/Views/Fonts/UniversLTStd-Ex.otf#Univers LT Std 53 Extended"
                                TextBlock.FontSize="12"
                                TextBlock.FontWeight="Normal"
                                TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource Black13}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Task}"
                              >
```

Comment: can you also include the screenshot of the misplaced combobox?

Comment: the combobox itself is in the correct place. the dropdown list appears in my case on my left screen at 0,0.
doesn't really matter where my application is it will still render the list in the upper left corner of my second screen.

but I cannot make a screenshot because the application is still under NDA.

Comment: see if this helps: [comboox popup (all popups) have suddnely started appearing in the top left of the screen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ad29ee3-e812-48bf-b6ee-aa16bc525ef7/comboox-popup-all-popups-have-suddnely-started-appearing-in-the-top-left-of-the-screen?forum=wpf)

Comment: same answer from the ones I found sadly...

it is a wpf bug and everyone tries a workaround, but it always depends on the situation. :(
no real solution usable sadly.

Comment: Which version of WPF are you using and what is the targeted plaform? Some times ago, I ran into similar problems when targeting .Net 4.0 from a recent Visual Studio. When building the same application on an earlier version, these issues did not appear.

Comment: Visual studio 2013 .NET version 4.5.1 and the target platform is PC windows 7/8

Comment: have you also bound the Width of some control with the ActualWidth of some other control? In the above social-msdn link the OP seems to have resolved the issue by removing that binding.

Comment: I have tried that, but no, sadly that is not the issue. When I try to set the width and height the problem does not disappear.
The combobox does appear in the correct position but the dropdownlist of the comboboxs doesn't.

Comment: The problem is fixed by a colleague of me. It seemed to be linked to a relative source connection with parents which searched too far.